# Xcode is not getting the image from xcassets

Tags: xcode, ios7

I have a list of images as shown below.

[image: My xcassets]

I am trying to retrieve the image from code. (Debugger shows you the name of file, which exists in the xcassets)

[image]

Unfortunately, I am getting nil when I call the [UIImage ImageNamed:filename].
What is wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you don't use the Unicode suit characters in your file names? That would seem to be the obvious possible issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

Please double check that the logged value in the debugger is not having any white space, also give it a try by hard coding the image name

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"K♥"];
```

May be this would help.

Comment: I just checked that Unicode suit characters have no issues with that, and it worked for me using xcode assets.

Comment: My program used ascii but image seemed like unicode. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

For special characher as à è ì ò ù this worked for me

yourString.**decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping**

as

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-icon",category.decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are now passing all the special characters the way they are = pictographs.

But instead, try adding them to an NSString with their corresponding unicode representation

```
@"K\u2665" for @"K♥"
@"K\u2660" for @"K♠"
@"K\u2667" for @"K♦"
@"K\u2663" for @"K♣"
```

If you want to know more on NSString and unicode, please refer to [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/unicode.html) latest article of objc.io on NSString and Unicode. Definitely a great read!